# std::bad_alloc error when declaring struct table

Tags: c++, c

I declared simple structure:

```
struct Heap {
  int size;
  int *heap_array;
};
```

When Im trying to create table, where `k` is int from stdin:

```
Heap *rooms = new Heap[k];
```

I got:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Using int literally everything is ok:

```
Heap *rooms = new Heap[0];
```

How to declare such table?

Comment: There is nothing wrong I see unless `k` has some crap in it. Try debugging the what the value of `k` is ?

Comment: Most probably you don't read `k` correctly. Making it a big number. That would result in a bad alloc.

Comment: What is `k`, what's the code to read input?

Comment: Yes, you were right, what a pity :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are your value read from `stdin` was invalid.  If the read failed you might have some default value in it like 2^32.

Comment: Or, if `k` is an `int`, the value could be negative.